# Springboot SOAP message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-services, soap

I'm looking for some guidance on SOAP endpoints with spring boot, the payload is received by the endpoint service but for some reason it can't be mapped.

```
2021-09-14 14:01:22.836 DEBUG 19864 --- [nio-7679-exec-1] .WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter : Accepting incoming [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpServletConnection@332ea0ee] at [http://localhost:7679/mockFMNP]
2021-09-14 13:58:50.468 TRACE 19864 --- [nio-7679-exec-1] o.s.ws.server.MessageTracing.received    : Received request [<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns3:NPDPortRequest xmlns:ns3="urn:FMNP"><inputXML>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;
&lt;FMNP&gt;
    &lt;PortRequest&gt;
        &lt;Operator&gt;XXXX-00077009&lt;/Operator&gt;
        &lt;RetryFlag&gt;N&lt;/RetryFlag&gt;
        &lt;Recipient&gt;XXXX&lt;/Recipient&gt;
        &lt;Donor&gt;17687&lt;/Donor&gt;
        &lt;MSISDN&gt;353999999599&lt;/MSISDN&gt;
        &lt;PortRequestDts&gt;2021-09-14T13:51:50Z&lt;/PortRequestDts&gt;
    &lt;/PortRequest&gt;
    &lt;Header&gt;
        &lt;Consumer&gt;XXXX&lt;/Consumer&gt;
        &lt;VersionNumber&gt;1.00&lt;/VersionNumber&gt;
        &lt;MessageDts&gt;2021-09-14T13:51:50Z&lt;/MessageDts&gt;
    &lt;/Header&gt;
&lt;/FMNP&gt;
</inputXML></ns3:NPDPortRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>]
2021-09-14 13:58:50.468 DEBUG 19864 --- [nio-7679-exec-1] yloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping : Looking up endpoint for [{urn:FMNP}NPDPortRequest]
2021-09-14 13:58:50.468 DEBUG 19864 --- [nio-7679-exec-1] o.s.w.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher  : Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@670024f4] has no mapping for request
```

My endpoint receiver is setup as

```
public static final String TARGET_NAME_SPACE = "urn:FMNP";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = TARGET_NAME_SPACE , localPart = "FMNP" )
    @ResponsePayload
    public String testE(@RequestPayload NPDPortRequest request) {
        System.out.println("In here....");
        return "test";
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your `localPart` is wrong.

Comment: Any idea what is should be? I've tried "NPDPortRequest" and same error

Comment: Looking at this it looks like it should be `NPDPortRequest`.